# Starting Mongo manually on OSX, won't stay up

Tags: macos, mongodb

I downloaded a database snapshot from a hosted service and am attempting to start `mongod` from the command line and pointing `--dbpath` at the expanded dump directory. It runs, but won't stay up. I get the following:

`2016-07-07T21:30:54.883-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1782 port=27017 dbpath=/Users/nate/Downloads/2016-07-07_21-10-23_UTC_pixwel_prod-deployment 64-bit host=lappy3.local
2016-07-07T21:30:54.884-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
2016-07-07T21:30:54.884-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
2016-07-07T21:30:54.884-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
2016-07-07T21:30:54.884-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-07-07T21:30:54.884-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-07-07T21:30:54.884-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-07-07T21:30:54.884-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-07-07T21:30:54.884-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-07-07T21:30:54.884-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/Users/nate/Downloads/2016-07-07_21-10-23_UTC_pixwel_prod-deployment" } }
2016-07-07T21:30:54.885-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /Users/nate/Downloads/2016-07-07_21-10-23_UTC_pixwel_prod-deployment created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
2016-07-07T21:30:54.897-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/Users/nate/Downloads/2016-07-07_21-10-23_UTC_pixwel_prod-deployment/journal
2016-07-07T21:30:54.898-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2016-07-07T21:30:54.917-0400 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2016-07-07T21:30:54.918-0400 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2016-07-07T21:30:55.206-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Old 2.4 style user index identified. The authentication schema needs to be updated by running authSchemaUpgrade on a 2.6 server.
2016-07-07T21:30:55.206-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2016-07-07T21:30:55.206-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-07-07T21:30:55.206-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2016-07-07T21:30:55.206-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-07-07T21:30:55.206-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-07-07T21:30:55.207-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2016-07-07T21:30:55.207-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2016-07-07T21:30:55.503-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2016-07-07T21:30:55.503-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2016-07-07T21:30:55.503-0400 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Terminating durability thread ...
2016-07-07T21:30:55.540-0400 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2016-07-07T21:30:55.540-0400 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2016-07-07T21:30:55.540-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2016-07-07T21:30:55.542-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2016-07-07T21:30:55.542-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2016-07-07T21:30:55.542-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 4`

Apparently `dbexit:  rc: 4` is not a super popular exit code, so Google isn't turning up much.

I've tried running with `--repair` beforehand. It runs and exits successfully, but has no effect.

Comment: The reason for shutdown is that you are attempting to use a database with 2.4 auth in 3.2: `Old 2.4 style user index identified. The authentication schema needs to be updated by running authSchemaUpgrade on a 2.6 server`. Try starting with MongoDB 2.4 or 2.6 instead of 3.2. The old 2.4 auth schema needs to be updated using MongoDB 2.6 before upgrading to newer server versions.

Comment: Thanks! If this were posted as an answer instead of a comment, I would totally accept it. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for shutdown is that you are attempting to use a database with unsupported 2.4 auth schema in 3.2:

```
2016-07-07T21:30:55.206-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Old 2.4 style user index
identified. The authentication schema needs to be updated by running authSchemaUpgrade
on a 2.6 server.
```

There have been several changes to authentication in the 3+ years (and 3 major releases so far) since MongoDB 2.4 was released. Skipping intervening auth upgrades is not supported, so instead of continuing the server is intentionally shutting down so you can upgrade properly.

The authentication schema needs to be updated by running the [authSchemaUpgrade](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/authSchemaUpgrade/) command on a 2.6 server before before upgrading to newer server versions.

There's actually a newer [authSchemaUpgrade](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/) for MongoDB 3.0+ which changes the authentication from the older MONGO-CR (Challenge-Response authentication) to the more secure (and standard) [SCRAM-SHA-1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/) mechanism. The 3.0 `authSchemaUpgrade` command expects the 2.6 authentication schema.

Instead of upgrading, you should also be able to use your data backup with MongoDB 2.4 or 2.6.